# Java Swing Components not working in public void main(String[]args)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm running the main method by clicking a jButton in this class. First tried by using

```
public static void main(String[]args)
```

All the java swing components started to show **non static variable cannot be referenced from static content** errors. So I changed

```
public static void main(String[]args)
```

to

```
public void main(String[]args)
```

No errors shown for the swing components but expected result are not displaying in the jTextArea. IF i print the expected output in System.out.println, it shows correctly. What am I doing wrong here? This is how i trigger main() to run by clicking on jButton

```
jButton4.setText("Analyze");
   jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
         try{
            TestTextRazor test = new TestTextRazor();
            test.main(new String[0]);
            } 
         catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
});
```

This is my  main()

```
public void main(String[] args) throws NetworkException, AnalysisException {

    File textSRC = new File("MyText.txt");
    String myTextCount = null;
    BufferedReader myTextBr = null;
    String check = "";
    try {
        String myTextCurrentLine;
        myTextBr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textSRC));
        while ((myTextCurrentLine = myTextBr.readLine()) != null) {
            myTextCount = myTextCount + " " + myTextCurrentLine;
        }

        // Sample request, showcasing a couple of TextRazor features
        String API_KEY = "7d5066bec76cb47f4eb4e557c60e9b979f9a748aacbdc5a44ef9375a";

        TextRazor client = new TextRazor(API_KEY);

        client.addExtractor("words");
        client.addExtractor("entities");
        client.addExtractor("entailments");
        client.addExtractor("senses");
        client.addExtractor("entity_companies");

        String rules = "entity_companies(CompanyEntity) :- entity_type(CompanyEntity, 'Company').";

        client.setRules(rules);

        AnalyzedText response = client.analyze(myTextCount);

        File file = new File("Hello1.txt");
        // creates the file
        file.createNewFile();
        // creates a FileWriter Object
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file); 
        // Writes the content to the file


        for (Sentence sentence : response.getResponse().getSentences()) {
            for (Word word : sentence.getWords()) {
                System.out.println("----------------");
                System.out.println("Word: " + word.getLemma());

                for (Entity entity : word.getEntities()) {
                ///System.out.println("Matched Entity: " + entity.getEntityId());
                }
                for (Sense sense: word.getSenses()) {
                //System.out.println("Word sense: " + sense.getSynset() + " has score: " + sense.getScore());
                }                
            }
         }

            // Use a custom rule to match 'Company' type entities

         for (Custom custom : response.getResponse().getCustomAnnotations()) {
            for (Custom.BoundVariable variable : custom.getContents()) {
                if (null != variable.getEntityValue()) {
                    for (Entity entity : variable.getEntityValue()) {
                        String CompanyFound = ("Variable: " + variable.getKey() +"\n"+ "Value:" + entity.getEntityId());
                        System.out.println(CompanyFound);
                        jTextArea3.append(CompanyFound);

                        writer.write(CompanyFound); 
                        writer.flush();
                        writer.close();
                    }
                }
            }
         }
         String ObjButtons[] = {"Yes","No"};
         int PromptResult;
         PromptResult = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Completed Analysis!\nIs there any error in the Analysis?","Homonym Entity Extraction Application",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,null,ObjButtons,ObjButtons[1]);

         //JOptionPane.getAlignmentX(Component.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);
         if(PromptResult==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
         {
             System.out.println("YEs!!!!!");
            jTextArea2.setEditable(true);
            jTextArea3.setEditable(true);
            jButton4.setEnabled(false);
            jButton5.setEnabled(true);
         } 
         else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Completed Analysis!","Alert", 1);
            System.out.println("No!!!!!!!!!!");
            jTextArea2.setEditable(false);
            jTextArea3.setEditable(false);
            jButton4.setEnabled(false);
         }


    }catch (IOException ex) {
    }

}
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Please, please get a book and read it. Learn what "static" means.

Comment: Fix you first error (non-static from static context)

Comment: For `Swing` programs, I wouldn't put so much in the `main` method, Take a look at some of the [`Swing tutorials`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) where you may pick up some better practices. May help you avoid this `static` problem in the future, also.

Answer (score 1):

Firs of all, what you need to understand is that a `static` method *cannot* access class *fields* or other methods that are `non-static`. So look at your code. The `main` *has* to be `static` as that is its natural signature, which *must* remain in tact as is. So all your class fields that you are trying to access in the `main` method, *need* to be `static`. Is this good practice? Absolutely not. You can browse through the [`Swing tutorial`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) to pick up on good practices. I'm sure if you run through 20 examples, you'll pick up on a lot of good coding practices for Swing. Good Luck!

---

> "*I'm running the main method by clicking a jButton in this class"*

- One thing I noticed that you are doing *complete* wrong is trying to call the `main` method from inside your `actionPerformed`. The `main` method should never be called. The JVM using that method as an entry point for your program.
- Another thing you have to understand is that a Swing program is event-driven. One button, should not run a complete program, unless it is a *very small* program.
- I would consider creating methods for different tasks like

  ```
  public String getSomethingFromFile(String filename) throws IOExceptions {

  }
  ```

  where you can call that method from an `actionPerformed` or something to append data to a text area.
- Learn to use class members and initialize them in your constructor or some initialization method.
- **If you want everything that's going on the `main` method to be performed on a button click, put all that code in the `actionPerformed`** , not in the `main`. A typical form of what goes inside the `main` is just something like this, where you just need to initialize your class to get the program running

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args){
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
          public void run(){
              JFrame frame = new JFrame();
              frame.add(new MyGUIPanel());
              frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
              frame.pack();
              frame.setVisible(true);
          }
      });
  }
  ```

  where `new MyGUIPanel()` is an instance of your Main class
- Another option is to create a method to perform all the tasks that are in the `main` like

  ```
  public void performTextRazorTask() throws NetworkException, AnalysisException {
      ...
  }
  ```

  and just call that method from the `actionPerformed`

---

Again, I stress that you have a look at the tutorials I linked for better practices, as this site isn't really a tutorial site, I don't want to get into a tutorial type answer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the error is saying, you are trying to reference non-static variables from a static context.

Non-static variables (often referred to as instance variables or fields) require an instance of their parent class in order to have some kind referencing context.

Take a look at [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for more details.

Without much more of an example to go by, I would create a class constructor and move the contents of the `main` method to it.

I would then fix the `main` method to be `static` and create a new instance of the class from the `main` method...

The reason I would refrain from making Swing components `static` is it's way to easy to mix up you references and end up referencing something that isn't actually displayed on the screen...

**Updated**

Two things.

1. Make sure that the context of your `main` method is correct, that the UI components that you have created are not `static` and you are referencing them correctly.
2. Don't call the [`TestTextRazor`](https://github.com/TextRazor/textrazor-java/blob/master/test/com/textrazor/TestTextRazor.java) class directly.  This is just an example of how the API works.  Take the time to understand it and incorporate into your own class(es) as required

Comment: The codes in main are not running outside main(). Its TextRazor API package that i got from gitHub.

Comment: Did you write the code in the `main` method?  If not, then you need to go back to the people that did and get them to fix it...

Comment: Alright @MadProgrammer, if there is any suggestion on TextRazor reference please post it here? I need guide on integrating TextRazor API in java.

Comment: Did you write the `main` method?

Comment: Personally, I probably wouldn't be running there "test" class...

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can not make main method as non static.

As per this line *non static variable cannot be referenced from static content errors.* make those variables as `static`

Comment: How can i make swing components as static?

Comment: @user3003233 Thogh I am not experieced in swing but I will try to help you.Can you post the full code so that I will run in my system and tell you where to make changes

Comment: @user3003233 Yes you can, no you shouldn't

Comment: @MadProgrammer I was thinking of you why till now you have not posted answer.

Comment: @JqueryLearner Debugging Json response :P, multiple threaded file processing and other general fun stuff ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am deleting this answer,Please help this user

Comment: It's hard to explain is the the user doesn't understand the concept of `static`

Comment: @peeskillet may the user is new to java.But he has atleast given some try.So thinking to help